# Django 1.5 and Heroku: My admin main has no links to anything

Tags: django, heroku

As I said above, I'm using Django 1.5 and Heroku. Everything works fine locally, but in the Heroku admin I just get the main page and that's it. There are no links to my app or anything in the "auth" category or ANYTHING. The image below is what comes up.

[image: here's the image]

As you can see, no links, no buttons, nothing but text.

Has anyone experienced before or have any ideas? I would be happy to post my code, but I don't want to overload this with useless junk so ask and I'll be happy to add whatever info you might want to see.

Some basic things:

Settings.py snippets:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

#'gunicorn',
#'django_evolution',
#Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
'CRM',
)
```

urls.py snippet:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
#Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^/', include('CRM.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
}),
)

admin.autodiscover()
```

Everything is registered in my admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! Yay! For those of you in the near or distant future that suffer from this, you need admin.autodiscover() at the TOP of your urls.py file.

Comment: Good bless you! ;-) Django newbie say THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome! I spent days with my head in my hands wondering why nothing would work. Best of luck!